# how to delete all documents on firestore using javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i try this code for my project but on `doc.reference.delete()` is not working

```
 btnSubmit.addEventListener('click', e => {
    db.collection("ruangIGD")
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots

            doc.reference.delete()
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```

how to solve this?

Comment: Have a look at the official documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#collections. You will see that "Deleting collections from a Web client is not recommended.". You will also find there a link to a proposed approach with a Callable Cloud Function: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections. If you get problems implementing this approach, do not hesitate to answer to this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, db have to be a const ! I think there is the problem

```
const db = new Firestore({
  projectId: "projectId",
  keyFilename: "./key.json"
 });
db.collection("collectionName")
  .get()
  .then(res => {
    res.forEach(element => {
      element.ref.delete();
    });
 });
```

Comment: i just take `element.ref.delete();` from your code and my code is working!
 thanks a lot dude!